# Intersection of Cut Locuses

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $C_p(M)$ is the cut locus of some $p\in M$ in some Riemannian Manifold $M$, then when is:
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{p\in M} C_p(M)=\emptyset\text{ ?}
\end{equation}

Comment: Any background? Motivation? Where does this question come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always, since $p\not\in C_p(M).$

Comment: Thanks that was obvious :)

Comment: But would this refined version still hold (this is what I meant to ask): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1380184/countable-intersection-of-cut-locuses-is-always-empty