# Countable intersection of Cut Locuses is always empty?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If $C_p(M)$ is the cut locus of some $p\in M$ in some Riemannian Manifold $M$, then does there *always* exist a countable collection of points $\{p_n\}_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that:
\begin{equation}
\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} C_{p_n}(M)=\emptyset\text{ ?}
\end{equation}

This is true for trivial example of $S_n$, simply take two distinct points but does this hold in general?
2.  If not what are the necessary conditions for it to hold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For each $p\in M$, the set $U_p = M\smallsetminus C_p$ is a neighborhood of $p$, and these neighborhoods cover $M$. Every open cover of a manifold has a countable subcover.

[Note that the question in your title is different from the one you asked in the text, and has a different answer -- it's certainly possible to find a countable collection of cut loci whose intersection is nonempty.]